# variable assignment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not understand why my variable assignment: `var mn = $("nav");` is not working in this piece of code:

```
var mn = $("nav");
var randomNum = 23;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > 400 ) {
    $("nav").addClass("main-nav-scroll");
    alert(randomNum);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass("main-nav-scroll");
  }
});
```

When I manually write it out in `$("nav").addClass(...);` it works perfectly. I thought the problem was maybe the scope of the variable so I added the `randomNum` variable to print out and it does so just fine. I'm really stumped. It took me forever to find this simple error So I'd like to understand for next time. Thanks.

Comment: Is `nav` an ID or a class?

Comment: Is the code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @John: Most likely it’s a [`nav` _element_](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) …

Comment: What do you see in the console if you add `console.log(mn)` to the `scroll` event handler?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Comment: @Barmar I think this is the problem. I'm super new to to this and so I don't fully understand the purpose of $(document).ready() nor do I know exactly how to implement it. But I'm going to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely `nav`.  It is a dom element just like `<p>`.  So when you try to select it your query is to general.

Give nav and ID and select it that way.

For example

**HTML**

```
<nav id "foob"></nav>
```

**JS**

```
var mn = $("#foob");
```

**In Addition**

Also, put a `console.log('scroll event fired')` in your event handler so that you can verify that the event is actually firing.

Comment: well based on what the question said, if that's the case then writing $("nav").addClass(...); manually wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This  works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($selimatac) {

    // öncelikle divi bir gizleyelim
    $selimatac("#yukari").hide();

    //scroll eğer 100 değerinin üstünde ise divi görünür yapacak, değilse gizleyecektir
    $selimatac(function () {

        $selimatac(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($selimatac(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $selimatac('#yukari').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $selimatac('#yukari').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // butona tıklayınca sayfa en üste çıkması için
        $selimatac('div a').click(function () {
            $selimatac('window,html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Look at http://selimatac.net/jquery-scrolltop-ile-yukari-cik-butonu/ for more information.

Comment: Please read the formatting help in the text editing box. Proper formatting is essential for readability, for the the person asking the question, and for those searching for similar answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your var gets rewritten somewhere in your code. Try another var name